# How to do an inner join while preserving other columns for group_concat?

Tags: mysql, join

Let's say I have these three tables: users, categories, and users_categories (many-to-many).

I'm trying to get all of the users and their categories, so it would be something like this:

```
SELECT users.*, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT categories.name separator '/') clist 
FROM users
LEFT JOIN users_categories ON users_categories.user = users.id
LEFT JOIN categories ON categories.id = users_categories.category
```

Pretty simple. Now, the hard part, is I want to display all the users that are in a particular category, but still maintain the same list of categories in the GROUP_CONCAT. Doing the following query shows only the users in a particular category as expected, but truncates the rest of the categories he belongs in:

```
SELECT users.*, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT categories.name separator '/') clist 
FROM users
LEFT JOIN users_categories ON users_categories.user = users.id
LEFT JOIN categories ON categories.id = users_categories.category
INNER JOIN categories cmust ON cmust.id = categories.id AND cmust.name = 'categoryhere'
```

How would I change this last query? Thanks.

EDIT: Sample data with just column names:

USERS table:

```
id, name:
1, myname
2, anothername
3, hisname
```

CATEGORIES table:

```
id, name
1, music
2, art
3, sports
```

USERS_CATEGORIES table:

```
user, category
1,1
1,2
2,2
3,1
3,3
3,2
```

Desired query result WITHOUT search category (as in my first query):

```
users.id,users.name,clist
1,'myname','music/art'
2,'anothername','art'
3,'hisname','music/sports/art'
```

Desired query result WITH search category. Let's say, only users in the 'music' category.
users.id,users.name,clist

```
1,'myname','music/art'
3,'hisname','music/sports/art'
```

This last one is what I want to accomplish. I basically just want to remove the users NOT in the specified category, and still retain the rest of the categories they belong to.

Comment: Can you post some sample data please?

Comment: sample data and wished results

Comment: @echo_me Just added some sample data, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may look for this

```
    SELECT users.*, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT categories.name separator '/') clist 
    FROM users
    LEFT JOIN users_categories ON users_categories.user = users.id
    LEFT JOIN categories ON categories.id = users_categories.category
    group by users.id
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3efcf/9)

and if you want to get categories with search category you can do this

```
SELECT users.*, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT categories.name separator '/')  clist 
FROM users
LEFT JOIN users_categories ON users_categories.user = users.id
LEFT JOIN categories ON categories.id = users_categories.category
group by users.id
having GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT categories.name separator '/') like '%music%'
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3efcf/30)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the following code:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (
SELECT users.*, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT categories.name separator '/') clist 
  FROM users
       LEFT JOIN users_categories ON users_categories.user = users.id
       LEFT JOIN categories ON categories.id = users_categories.category
       ) a
 WHERE '/'+a.clist+'/' LIKE '/'+'categoryhere'+'/';
```

Note: Use a proper MySQL string concatenation operator in the line in the `WHERE` clause. This will give you your desired result.

Comment: This would work, but since there could be multiple categories in `clist`, I think that just matching it is kind of a rough work around. Is there no direct method that would use less overhead? Also, see my original post, I added sample data. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the result you want by starting from the desired categories, then finding the users in that/these category(/ies), and then proceed as in your original query.

The benefit of this method is that you easily can search more than one category at once, *i.e* finding *e.g* users belonging to the categories music OR art.

```
SELECT users.*, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT categories.name separator '/') clist 
FROM categories C1
INNER JOIN users_categories UC1 ON UC1.category = C1.id
INNER JOIN users ON users.id = UC1.user
INNER JOIN users_categories ON users_categories.user = users.id
INNER JOIN categories ON categories.id = users_categories.category
WHERE C1.name IN ('music') 
group by users.id
```